# bash: only iterate through files, not sub-directories?

Tags: bash

Is there a simple option to accomplish iterating through files and not subdirectories in the bash for loop construct:

```
 for file in /some-dir/*
```

?  If not, how is this best done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to loop and put an explicit continue on directories:

```
for file in /some-dir/*; do
  [[ -d $file ]] && continue
done
```

Another is to use extglob syntax (this example tested to work on bash 4.x):

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in some-dir/!(*/); do
  echo "Found $file"
done
```

Another is to use `find` -- see below for an example of how to do this carefully:

```
# Using file descriptor 3 so stdin is unmodified
# ...choose another FD number if you like.
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 3 filename; do
  : "$filename"
done 3< <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Comment: for simple cases you really don't need to use the 3rd descriptor.

Comment: @jm666, sure, but I don't want to show something that's going to be fragile if reused in more interesting scenarios. Better to teach people how to do things right than have folks getting used to writing code in ways that'll be buggy if circumstances differ.

Comment: Thanks Charles.   Option 3, using find, seems the most cryptic.  Can you please give me your thoughts on choosing between options 1 and 2?

Comment: @Ray, I'd use option 1 if you need to support older versions of bash (through 2.x), or option 2 if you only need to support bash 4.x and forward -- extglobs do exist in 3.x, but their behavior isn't quite identical.

Comment: ...also, you could easily make option 1 POSIX-compliant by making it `[ -d "$file" ] && continue`, and then it'll work even with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Ray, ...btw, if you'd like to get a better handle on the practices used in option 3 and why they're important to know, I'd suggest reading BashFAQ entries #1 and #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024